# Find an expression for the position at time $t$.

Tags: calculus, physics

Suppose a unit of mass moves on a straight line (in one dimension). The position of the mass at time $t$ (in seconds) is denoted by $s(t)$, and its derivatives, velocity and acceleration, by $s'(t)$ and $s''(t)$ respectively. The position as a function of time can be determined from Newton’s second law
$$s''(t) = F(t)$$
where $F(t)$ is the force applied at time $t$, and the initial conditions are $s(0), s'(0)$. We assume $F(t)$ is piecewise-constant, and is kept constant in intervals of one second. Let $f_{k}=F(t)$ for $k-1 \le t < 3$. Find an expression for $s(3)$.

What I've done so far:

$$s(t)-s(0) = \int_{0}^{t} s'(u) \,d u$$

I'm supposed to use $$\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{3}} s'(u) \,du = \int_{0}^{1} s'(u) \,du + \int_{1}^{2} s'(u) \,du + \int_{2}^{3} s'(u) \,du$$

but I'm not exactly sure what to set $s'(u)$ equal to

Comment: Wouldn't $s'(t) - s'(0)$ be some integral of $s''$?

Comment: @Eric Towers: yes, so for $t \in [2,3)$ for example, $s'(t) = s'(0) + f_{1} + f_{2} + f_{3}?$ But I know that I'm supposed to get a fraction of $\dfrac{f_{3}}{2}$ somehow. Although, I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: $\int \int c \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}x = \int (cx + C_1) \,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{cx^2}{2} + C_1 x + C_2$.

Comment: @Eric Towers: so $c$ would be some $f_{k}?$. Also, for the problem that I'm given, would I have to do a double definite integral?

Comment: Yes.  $F$ is constant (on each one second interval).

Comment: Yes.  You would have definite integrals (with bounds for each the ends of each one second interval on which $F$ is constant).

Comment: @Erice Towers: is it just the outer integral that's definite? if I do $\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} f_{1} \,dx \,dx$, then I just end up with $\int_{0}^{1} f_{1} \,dx$

Comment: Look back at my first comment and remember that you are doing all this integration to get $s'(t)$, not $s'(1)$.

Comment: @Eric Towers: I used $s'(1)$ as an example

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

If $F(t)=f_k$  for all $t$ such that $k-1\leq t < k$, $k\in \{1,2,3\}$, then $$s(t) = 0.5f_k t^2 + g_kt +h_k$$ on that interval, for some constants $g_k$ and $h_k$.

Initial conditions give:
$$ h_1 = s(0),$$
$$ g_1 = s^\prime(0).$$

Also, as $s$ and $s^\prime$ are continuous at $k$, we have

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow k^-}s(t) = s(k),$$
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow k^-}s^\prime(t) = s^\prime(k),$$
for $k\in \{1,2\}$. These equalities provide $g_2, h_2$ and $g_3, h_3$.

Finally, using continuity of $s$ at $3$, we get:

$$ s(3) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 3^-}s(t) =4.5f_3  + 3g_3 +h_3.$$